# How to fix Visual C++ Formula used to find angle of launched projectile

Tags: c++

Im trying to calculate the angle needed for projectile to hit a target

Ive brought forward the formula from this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile

here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#include <iomanip>

#define PI  3.14159

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y, v;
    double g = 9.81;
    double angleoffire1;
    double angleoffire2;



    cout << "input difference in distance between position and target\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "input difference in altitude between position and target\n";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "input velocity of projectile\n";
    cin >> v;

    angleoffire1 = atan((pow(v, 2) + sqrt(pow(v, 4) - g*(g*pow(x, 2) + 2 * y*pow(v, 2)))) / g*x)*(180 / PI);
    angleoffire2 = atan((pow(v, 2) - sqrt(pow(v, 4) - g*(g*pow(x, 2) + 2 * y*pow(v, 2)))) / g*x)*(180 / PI);

    cout << setprecision(16) << angleoffire1 << "this is the angle of fire for high traj\n";
    cout << setprecision(16) << angleoffire2 << "this is the angle of fire for low traj\n";




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it is capable of producing results, but they are all either too high (consistently 89 degrees) or non-valid numbers (-1.#IND)

i humbly ask for assistance on this matter

Comment: could you share some numeric example you have? I think your atan is messing the result... maybe it has an atan2 implementation?

Comment: `atan2(y, x)` is generally better if you need to compute `atan(y / x)`

Comment: Break the large formula down into separate distinct steps (e.g. for `g*pow(x, 2)` you do `pow(x, 2)` and `g * previous_result`), then do them all on paper, and finally step through the code to see the results, and compare them to what you got in your own calculations on paper. When they start to differ too much, you will know which step causes the trouble.

Comment: @AlanStokes thank you so much it works no words can express my lewd gratitude for your assistance

Comment: @Topol-M I don't think "lewd" means what you think it does. :-)

Comment: I think the problem is with the g\*x term in the denominators of your formulas. As it is written now, the argument of atan in your formulas is equivalent to numerator\*x/g, while you actually want numerator/(g*x).

Comment: @Alan tokes I cant grind on you accross the internet no?

Comment: Is sqrt's argument always positive?